# Azure Devops Pipeline builder unable to see namespace in referenced dll

Tags: c#, azure, namespaces, azure-pipelines

In my application I have 2 projects.

One project has the namespace `CustomerManager`.

Within it there are multiple folders with their own namespaces e.g. `CustomerManager.UI` or `CustomerManager.BLL`.

I have a reference to `CustomerManager` in my other project and a using statement for `CustomerManger.UI`.

Both projects are using the same .Net version.

The application works perfectly on my local machine, but when I try to build it using Azure Devops Pipeline builder I get this error:

> CustomerManager.StartUp\Program.cs(1,32): 
>   Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'CustomerManager' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: could you elaborate more how you are referring the projects

Comment: The CustomerManager.Startup project has a reference added under references from the  project solution list to CustomerManager.dll which contains CustomerManager.UI namespace as well as others. The Program.cs has this code : using CustomerManager.UI;

Comment: I've found a workaround which was to split the project which has multiple namespaces into multiple projects, each with a single namespace, this isn't ideal as the solution builds and runs fine locally it's just in devops pipeline where it fails. Ddoes anyone know of another solution?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this scenario, For troubleshooting, you can check  if the UI file is included in compile `<Compile Include="UI\UI.cs" />` in the csproj file of CustomerManager project. And in the csproj of the other project check if Customer project in included `<ProjectReference Include="..\MyApp\MyApp.csproj">`.